# python info function: where is it?

Tags: python

From [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/built_in_functions.html#d0e8958):

> Python has a function called info. Try it yourself and skim through
>   the list now.

```
>>> from apihelper import info
>>> import __builtin__
>>> info(__builtin__, 20)
ArithmeticError      Base class for arithmetic errors.
AssertionError       Assertion failed.
AttributeError       Attribute not found.
EOFError             Read beyond end of file.
EnvironmentError     Base class for I/O related errors.
Exception            Common base class for all exceptions.
FloatingPointError   Floating point operation failed.
IOError              I/O operation failed.
```

It turns out that Python **does not** have a function called **info**. What was the book referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why Dive Into Python claims that "Python has a function called `info`", but it's obviously not true.

`apihelper.py` (from which `info` is imported) is described earlier in the book, [in section 4.1](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html#apihelper.divein), and is just a module that Mark Pilgrim wrote for use with Dive Into Python. That `apihelper` module apparently does contain an `info` function that does what is claimed in section 4.3.3, which you linked.

Answer (score 1):

**apihelper** is a module from the book. You have to download it.

I found this link for this exemple and many others: http://www.diveintopython.net/download/diveintopython-examples-5.4.zip

Answer (score 0):

Python don't have that module i.e. apihelper.py but diveintopython made that function in their tutorial

```
  def info(object,spacing=10,collapse=1):
       availableMethod = [method for method in dir(object) if    callable(getattr(object,method))];
       processFunc = collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
       print "\n".join(["%s %s" % (method.ljust(spacing),processFunc(getattr(object, method).__doc__)) for method in availableMethod])
```

This is the function they have developed, that what they are referring to its in the file apihelper.py that's why

```
  from apihelper import info
```

hope it helps. :)